# How can I make neovim display the "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP" message like vim?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vimrc, neovim

Unlike vim, neovim does not display the `search hit BOTTOM` message when searching repeatedly for a string. Tested with neovim 0.6.1 on ubuntu, no init.vim and no pluins, and editing /etc/ssh/ssh_config and searching repeatedly for `Auth`.

A gdb breakpoint on `give_warning` in nvim does get reached, `VV_WARNINGMSG` gets set but instead of the warning, the searched string is displayed even when wrapping (unlike in vim, where the warning is displayed instead of the string).

Without this red warning, I can't tell when the search wraps, and I keep hitting `n` in an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently vim also exhibits this behavior, at least starting with vim 8.2, and it can be worked around in both vim and neovim with `:set shortmess+=S`. More info at https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/21646 .